# Highlight Excel Cells Using Conditonal Formatting Across Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am using Excel 2010. 
Using CONDITIONAL FORMATTING I am trying to highlight cells based on the following criteria.

`Sheet 1 ID (A2)` must equal `Sheet 2 ID (A2)` (they must match)
and then if `Sheet 2 Action` equals *"Insert"*, highlight the cell.

What I've tried
`=AND(Sheet1!$A2=Sheet2!$A2,Sheet2!$B2="INSERT")`

I would expect the cells with ID's 10, 4 and 2 to be highlighted in the linked image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuLzS.jpg)

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: That looks correct to me. What range did you apply it to?

Comment: Sorry I should have shown in the example data that the ID in sheet 2 is not in order i.e it could go 10, 5, 3, 1 etc. The range I am applying is =$A$2:$A$11

Comment: So you're checking for presence in both lists, rather than both being in the same position? Try `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$11,2,FALSE)="Insert",FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for your help that seemed to do the trick. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem - I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt compares each value in Sheet1 to the cell in the same position in Sheet2. To check for that value anywhere in your data range in Sheet2, and for the corresponding value in column B, use this instead:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$11,2,FALSE)="Insert",FALSE)
```